# Appium forces JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: java, android, testing, appium

Running autotests by pagefactory + testng + maven
1) start selenium grid:

```
java -jar \selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub
```

2) start appium servers:

```
appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4723 --bootstrap-port 4720 -U 3b06c2a2 --nodeconfig node_config_1.json

appium -a 127.0.0.1 -p 4725 --bootstrap-port 4729 -U LenovoTAB2A8 --nodeconfig node_config_2.json
```

3) Start tests:  mvn test

appium version: 1.6.3 / 1.5.3 /1.4 - checked on all versions.
node version: js node-v7.7.4-x64.msi
java 1.8 , Windows 7 x64

After 30minutes second appium (-p 4725) uses too mush RAM ~1.3Gb, when first one usese less RAM (-p 47253) ~300Mb

And after some time, appium(-p 4725) goes douwn

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

2558249 ms: Mark-sweep 1371.3 (1434.9) -> 1371.3 (1434.9) MB, 1745.2 / 0.0 ms [
allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
2559995 ms: Mark-sweep 1371.3 (1434.9) -> 1372.8 (1408.9) MB, 1745.4 / 0.0 ms [
last resort gc].
2561685 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.8 (1408.9) -> 1374.8 (1408.9) MB, 1689.8 / 0.0 ms [
last resort gc].

<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 000002B7252CFB61 
1: onread [net.js:530] [pc=000001837B14847C] (this=000000AC5570A169 <a Pipe
with map 0000008EE91F9D21>,nread=410,buffer=00000073E9AE60B9 <an Uint8Array with
map 0000008EE91F8671>)
2: arguments adaptor frame: 3->2

==== Details ================================================

[net.js:530] [pc=000001837B14847C] (this=000000AC5570A169 <a Pipe wi
th map 0000008EE91F9D21>,nread...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memo
ry
```

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely an issue: I cannot speak for older server version, but with *1.7.1* single node for me uses *115-180* Mb RAM and remains on that level within time.

Starting with Appium server *1.6.5* you can use `--enable-heapdump` server flag to turn on NodeJS memory dump collection. That might help you to investigate if the issue is in your infrastructure setup or its on appium server side.

You can also look into some alternatives to Selenium Grid like [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid)